# intellij idea maven dependencies resource code using decompiler

Tags: maven, intellij-idea-2016

It is said that Intellij idea would automatically download resource code from maven for maven projects. However I am still having "decompiled .class file bytecode version 50.0". I would like to view the resource code from .java. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on the project. maven -> download resources and documents (or just download resources). I have already checked the settings -> maven ->importing ->sources and documents, but this does not work no idea why.